# Program Spartan6 eFUSE key in w10

Tags: xilinx-ise, jtag, spartan

**I need help programing efuse registers on Spartan 6 from windows 10.**

- We have plethora of boards designed with the Spartan 6.
- We are currently programming them with an old Windows XP machine which needs to be retired and replaced with windows 10.
- The new Xilinx Vivado software doesn't support Spartan 6.
- The [Xilinx official installer](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/vivado-design-tools/archive-ise.html) for the legacy ISE software installs a Virtual Box VM but this can not program the efuse registers [probably because it is 64 bit.](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/FPGA-Configuration/Cannot-assess-efuse-register-on-64-bit-Windows-7-with-IMPACT-v14/td-p/799000)
- I have also followed a [hack](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/FPGA-Configuration/XILINX-TOOLS-iMPACT-64/td-p/1046790) shared on the forms to install iMPACT natively on windows 10, but this also can not access the efuse registers.
- I have [tried burning the key from the new toolset Vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug908-vivado-programming-debugging.pdf), but the instructions reference changing settings in the implementation project which doesn't exist for an unsupported chip.

Further effort:

- I am attempting to build my own 32bit Linux VM with the software tools installed, but getting the cable driver working has eluded me so far.
- I may reinstall windows 10 as 32 bit.

**Has anyone out there found a solution for programming Spartan 6 efuse registers from windows 10 or any other configuration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build my own 32bit Linux VM and get it to program the eFUSE registers.

- I used Debian 10 32bit.
- The desktop has to be gnome classic or mate for the windows to work.
- The both Xilinx old driver and it's Vivado driver will not work.  There is a [third party driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128841) with instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128841)